# Dynamic function creation and function body evaluation

Tags: python, function, dynamic

Consider the following Python 3 instructions

```
res = []
for a in range(3) :
    res.append(lambda n : n + a)
```

with the aim of building a list `res` of three functions `res[0]`, `res[1]`, and `res[2]` such that `res[i](n)` returns `n + i`, for all `i` in `[0, 1, 2]`.

Nevertheless, one obtains

```
>>> res[0](0)
2
```

instead of

```
>>> res[0](0)
0
```

One also have

```
>>> res[1](2)
4
```

The explanation of this behavior is that in the expression `n + a` in the body of any dynamically generated anonymous function of the example, the symbol `a` is not evaluated at the creation of the function. The evaluation is performed at the exit of the for statement, explaining why all functions `res[0]`, `res[1]`, and `res[2]` return the value of their argument plus `2è (because`a`browses`range(3)`and`2` is its last value).

Notice that the problem does not lie in the fact that we use anonymous functions. Indeed, the instructions

```
res = []
for a in range(3) :
    def f(n) :
        return n + a
    res.append(f)
```

lead to the same behavior.

Notice also that we can meet the objective set out above by using the function `eval` of Python:

```
res = []
for a in range(3) :
    s = "lambda n : n + %s" %(a)
    res.append(eval(s))
```

The trick lies on the fact that the dynamic value of `a` is considered for the creation of each function of `res`.

Now my questions are

1. is this a bug or a feature?
2. is there an other way not passing by `eval` to obtain the expected behavior?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do (lambda) function closures capture?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295290/what-do-lambda-function-closures-capture)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of [closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_programming%29) the dynamic functions referencing variable `a` and using the final value it had at the end of the `for` loop when they execute.

You can prevent that by making it an function argument with a default value so it doesn't need to be provided on calls. The value of `a` at the time each dynamic function is defined will become the value used. This is what I mean:

```
res = []
for a in range(3) :
    res.append(lambda n, a=a: n + a)

print(res[0](0))  # -> 0
print(res[1](2))  # -> 3
```

Comment: That makes it a two-argument function, though. Not so clean.

Comment: @StefanPochmann: Not really, as illustrated by the sample calls to the functions at the end. This is because values for arguments  with default values are optional.

Comment: Yes, it's optional, but it's still there.

Comment: @StefanPochmann: You're entitled to your own minority opinion, of course, but this is a common Python idiom to deal with issues like this and is very lightweight.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I tested it and it's indeed smaller and faster than mine. I'll keep it in mind.

Comment: Just one more thing: You say his functions are using the final value that `a` had at the end of the loop. While technically correct, I think this is misleading. They're only using that value because that's still the value `a` has when they're called. If you increase `a` further, even after having used the functions after the loop, then the functions use the new value, not the one it had at the end of the loop.

Comment: @StefanPochmann: That's exactly why I updated my answer to say that the dynamic functions _refer_ to the `a` variable...implying that they will pick up whatever value it has each time they're called.

Comment: I just think many won't get that but just understand and remember the *"the value it had at the end of the loop"* part.

Comment: @StefanPochmann: Well, if they follow the "not so clean" suggestion in my answer, it won't matter what value the loop variable has except when each function is defined.

Answer (score 2):

I cant speak to #1 ... except to say I am sure that is intentional and desirable behaviour for some definition of intentional and desirable

but WRT #2

```
res = []
for a in range(3) :
    res.append(lambda n,b=a : n + b)

res[0](0)
```

this will evaluate `a` as the default 2nd argument while inside the for loop(instead of after exiting) ...

of coarse this leaves it open to something like

```
res[0](0,8)
```

Answer (score 0):

This would also work, if you don't want to use `lambda`:

```
>>> from functools import partial
>>> for a in range(3) :
    def f(a, n):
        return n + a
    f = partial(f, a)
    res.append(f)

>>> res[0](0)
0
>>> res[1](2)
3
```

Answer (score 0):

This gives you clean functions which just have one argument:

```
res = []
for a in range(3) :
    res.append((lambda a: lambda n: n+a)(a))
```

Might be better for readability and efficiency to do it this way, though:

```
def adder(amount):
    return lambda n: n + amount

res = []
for a in range(3) :
    res.append(adder(a))
```

Also, your *"The evaluation is performed at the exit of the for statement"* is wrong. Try printing after the loop, then increase `a` further, then print again. You'll see that the functions now use the further increased value of `a` (only with your version, of course, not with mine). That's because your functions don't have their own `a` but use the same global `a`, and evaluate it whenever they're called.